# Google maps and plus one conflict

Tags: google-maps, google-plus-one

When you put a google map and a plus one button on the same page it seems to create some strange rendering issues. In these examples [WITH](http://benjaminchirlin.com/mechanism/maptestplusone.html) and [WITHOUT](http://benjaminchirlin.com/mechanism/maptest.html) the plus one button. If you click on a marker it will zoom in on it, then hit reset to zoom back out. You'll see the map doesn't render when the buttons included till you zoom in and out manually. Why? Anyone know a way around this?

EDIT: This issue seems to only happen in Google Chrome...IRONY!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Firefox 6.0, Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both worked fine for me in Firefox 6.  In IE9 the google +1 button didn't even show up at all.  No surprise there, really, although it should work.  That might be, however, because you don't have fully valid HTML in your test document (with html and body tags). You might want to try that first.

You can also try using the HTML 5 tag for the google plus one button.  I feel that is a safer alternative and it is fully HTML5-valid:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="250" ></div>
```

Check out the [+1 Button Reference](http://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) under "+1 Tag Attributes" for a complete list of possible attributes

Comment: Yeah I've been looking at it in Google Chrome. I still find it hilarious that Google APIs seem to not work as well in their own browser as in Firefox! In its original page it has all the necessary HTML, header, etc. tags and the issue persists. It must be a quirk in Chromes renderer.